# What is the number of microscopic states/configurations of a system? Are diffferent definitions consistent?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Suppose there is a Boltzman system, where $N$ particles are distinguishable, and we are counting the available microstates of a given energy $E$. We have
$$\Omega_{M.B}=\frac{N!}{\prod_l a_l!}\prod_l \omega_l^{a_l},$$
where $\omega_l$ is the degeneracy and $a_l$ is the number of particles in energy $E_l$ state.

Here, exchanges among $a_l$ particles of the same energy are not considered "new microscopic configuration".

However, when we are calculating the change of Gibbs free energy after the mix of 2 ideal gases. We have
$$G'=G-TS$$
$$S=K\ln\Omega$$
$$\Omega=\frac{(N_A+N_B)!}{N_A!N_B!}$$

I'm confused about why $\Omega$ in the second example is calculated like that. Why exchange of 2 different particles is a "new microscopic configuration"? What about exchange of 2 particles of the sanme kind( i.e. AA or BB)?

If this is just artificially defined，are the entropy and other thermodynamic functions consistent in different definition？

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the degeneracy of the exchange of particles is taken into account by counting $\omega_l$, whereas in the second case it isn't. Since you are considering distinguishable particles, exchanging two particles should be considered a "new microscopic configuration".

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding your first equation. Let us break it down.

The first part of your expression,
$$
\frac{N!}{\prod_{l} a_{l} !},
$$
is the number of ways to distribute $N$ distinct objects into $m$ distinct energy levels (where $m$ is the number of different energy levels). See [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). Now that we have all the ways to distribute the particles by the energy levels, let us focus on the distribution of particles inside each energy level. If the particles were indistinguishable, how many microstates would you have? You would have just one, because it is completely characterized by the number of particles. But you don't, you have
$$
\prod_{l} \omega_{l}^{a_l}.
$$
What does each term in the product, $\omega_{l}^{a_l}$, represent? It is the number of ways of distributing $a_l$ distinct objects in $\omega_{l}$ bins, such that you are counting each possible configurations of labelled particles within each energy level. By doing this for all energy levels, you get the product.

Moreover, your expression of the number of microstates maybe wrong, since you are assuming that all possible distribution of particles (all possible lists for the values of ${a_l}$ such that $\sum_l a_l = N$)  will have the same energy $E$.